# How to reference current dir from a terminal command

Tags: xcode, macos, terminal, xcrun

How do I reference the current dir from a terminal command:

```
xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v "[current dir]/target/My App.app" -o "[current dir]/target/MyApp.ipa"
```

> [current dir] = how do I get this value?

So basically I don't want to type the whole dir out in the command.  I want it to look in the dir where it is currently running

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v "$PWD/target/My App.app" -o "$PWD/target/MyApp.ipa"
```

Comment: see my update.  it works for the first instance but the second instance it looks in usr/bin for some or other reason.  I want it to place the .ipa in the target dir

Comment: `xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v "$PWD/target/My App.app" -o "$PWD/target/MyApp.ipa"` should work